# Spring 3.x WebFlux Gateway FormData Problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have gateway builded by spring reactor webflux and i have globalfilter for per request changes some fields.

I have an request , and this request has formData , form data includes files binary datas.

but after apply filter changes this formData is gone i can't reach this data.

This is my rewrite function:

```
    private void addQueryParam(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, String username) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        queryParams.add(routeData.getFieldName(), username);
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(
                            Objects.requireNonNull(serverWebExchange.getAttribute(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR)))
                .queryParams(queryParams).build().toUri();
        serverWebExchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, uri);
    }
```

When i want evaluate my serverWebExchange.getFormData().block() and i get error :

```
block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
```

how can avoid this problem , anyone has idea ?

I try to get form data and rewrite same request params but it's not work.

Comment: Your web server is based on `netty` and you need to return Mono or Flux respectively. You cannot use `block` method here.

Comment: okey but my formData is missing why i can't understand my data is deleting.. have an idea for this problem ? because i don't want return any data.